# Problem with installed color themes

Tags: themes

I re-installed Emacs and I tried to change the color theme. I saved the changes and the `.emacs` file was updated but when I restarted Emacs the theme was not active! I want to point out that the package is installed in the elpa folder. The theme was loaded when I pressed it and took effect but it was not working after the restart. When I did the same for the custom themes they were working fine. I had used the same theme previously with no problem. Also the problem is not because of the theme as I tried to install more with no success. What is the problem?

Comment: Are you using custom themes (i.e., http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Custom-Themes.html ), or the `color-theme` library (i.e., `color-theme-6.6.0.zip` from: http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/color-theme/ )?

Comment: @lawlist I am sorry but as I am new to Emacs I don't really know what you mean. I installed Emacs and having placed in the list of packages the Melpa archive I installed the themes via the `list-packages` as the first time.

Comment: Specifically, what package or theme did you install -- i.e., name of package or name of theme?

Comment: I tried a lot of themes (with the same result) but the one I used previously and I still want to use it the dakrone-theme.

Comment: The message that appears immediately after installing the `dakrone-theme` is:  "*A dark theme with lots of color.  To use, put the following in your Emacs config:  `(load-theme 'dakrone t)`.  Requires Emacs 24*."  So, the first question is:  Did you do that -- i.e., manually add `(load-theme 'dakrone t)` to your `.emacs` file?  The second question is:  Are you using a version of Emacs that is at least 24?  To answer the second question, you can type:  `M-x emacs-version RET`

Comment: @lawlist no I didn't manually add this. I installed it via the `list-packages` and I saved the changes for future sessions as I always do. My Emacs is 24.3.1.

Comment: Well, when all else fails, follow the instructions -- open up your `.emacs` file and add `(load-theme 'dakrone t)` -- preferably **at the bottom**.  Then restart Emacs.  If that works, then your error is probably higher up in your `.emacs` file -- i.e., Emacs loads settings from the top of the file to the bottom of the file, and the bottom is the last to load.  Also, check your `*Messages*` buffer to see if there is anything mentioned there about an error of some sort or another.

Comment: Yes, but I can't see your `.emacs` file because you haven't posted it.  So, I can only assume you've got other stuff in there that is causing some sort of conflict.  That is why I suggested placing that line of code **at the very bottom**.

Comment: @lawlist it doesn't work. I tried more themes and the same thing happens. Although the work in the beginning after the restart they don't.

Comment: You really only need three (3) lines of code in your `.emacs` file to make the theme work after it has been installed.  So, first install the theme, then back-up your `.emacs` file and save it somewhere else.  Create a new `.emacs` file and put the following three (3) lines of code -- with nothing else -- then, restart Emacs.  `(require 'package) (package-initialize) (load-theme 'dakrone t)`.  That's it -- it should just work!

Comment: Once you get it working **using the bare minimum** in your `.emacs` file, then go through the debugging procedure of using your old backed-up `.emacs` file and bisect it:  http://superuser.com/a/639664/206164.  When debugging, it is helpful to place `(setq debug-on-error t)` at the top of the `.emacs` file.

Comment: I had done done that and I had make my whole `.emacs` file a comment trying to see what was the problem. If you see the comment to your answer you will understand why there was no problem with my init file. :P thank you very much though for your suggestions and your answer that solved my problem.

Comment: @Adam, please don't tag all your questions with gnu-emacs. =) Have a look at the tag excerpt to see what it's about.

Comment: @Malabarba I am sorry I am still getting to know the terminology (tags) for a lot of Emacs' functions. I will try to find better tags :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**STEP 1**:  Place the following code in the `.emacs` file, and restart Emacs.

```
(require 'package)
 (add-to-list 'package-archives
   '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)
```

**STEP 2**:  `M-x list-packages RET`

**STEP 3**:  Click on and install `dakrone-theme`.

**STEP 4**:  Open up the `.emacs` file and add the following line of code **at the very bottom** and then restart Emacs:

```
(load-theme 'dakrone t)
```

**STEP 5**:  Crack open your favorite beverage and enjoy your new color theme.

Comment: Thank you your answer helped because of the `(package-initialize)`. I had forgotten to add it! I placed it in my `.emacs` and everything works great! Thank you for reminding me!

Comment: Glad to help -- the `package-initialize` function helps Emacs locate the appropriate contents of the `.emacs.d` directory and do whatever needs to be done with the installed packages.